# Command to get/clone a fetch/pull/read -only copy of a git repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Here's a git repository on github:

> git://github.com/Fudge/gltail.git

What's the simplest way to check out a read-only copy using the git command line tool?

**update:**  Here's a suggestion to the githubbers:  Do something similar to google code, which automatically displays a message such as:

```
Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:
    # Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
    svn checkout http://orapig.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ orapig-read-only
```

**update:** The githubbers have done this.

Comment: Note that git does not really have (or need to have) read-only copies. You will have a complete (local) copy of the repository, and can do with that what you please.

Comment: I'm just quoting from github (github.com/Fudge/gltail), which specifies the download as being "HTTP Read Only".

Comment: Maybe "pull/fetch only" would be more precise: it means you can retrieve over HTTP a copy of the repository, but you can't push via the same URL commits *into that particular repository on github*. Once you have your clone, you have a local copy of the entire history that you can manipulate however you like.

Comment: thanks for asking this question! couldn't github just said that?? cheers! +1

Comment: I have the same question, and also come from SVN where such things are easy and logical.  My usecase is i simply want to grab a copy of the latest version read only so I can run it on a server - i.e. use it as a simple deployment tool (deploy = grab head).  I dont want, or need a repo or history or ability to push back.

Comment: @JohnLittle, it turns out no matter what you get a local fully functioning repo.  You don't have permissions to write back to the source, so in that sense it's read-only.  For your needs, just do a "git clone", do whatever you need, and you can delete the cloned directroy as you like with no bad effects.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
git clone git://github.com/Fudge/gltail.git
```

Comment: Hello, @mipadi and how do i get the `git` command in terminal? **Github is already installed**. thanks

Comment: @AlexSanchez If it's already installed but in terminal you type git but not recognized, you may want to find the installation location of the git command, and add it into the path.

Comment: GitHub is generally referred to as a place where repositories or the code itself is installed. Git is generally referred to as the command line utility for interacting with repositories hosted on GitHub. Additionally, GitHub recently released a graphical desktop app for interacting with repositories which doesn't require using the 'git' command on the command line.

Comment: Note that as of 2022 this does not work any more, as GitHub has disabled `git://` protocol access for security reasons (specifically because it’s unencrypted).

Answer (score 23):

The question is a bit misleading. There's not really such a thing as a "read-only copy" of a `git` repository. You can clone an existing repository with:

```
git clone git://example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

But unlike Subversion, every "copy" in git is itself a completely new repository. Since you can commit to your own repository, it's certainly not read-only in that sense.

Comment: I'm just quoting from github (http://github.com/Fudge/gltail), which specifies the quote git: as being "HTTP Read Only".

Comment: @Mark: That just means that the http protocol for that repository is only configured to allow checkouts and pulls, not pushes.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't found a real "read-only copy", but you can approach it by this way depending on your need :

1) `git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/Fudge/gltail.git`
Explanation : as you ask for a copy, you may not be interested by the full history of that copy.
`--depth 1` option limits the download to the last version of the default branch and may reduce dramatically the amount of data to retrieve.

2) If you don't want to update your copy, you can remove the .git directory at the root of your copy : it will cut the link with the original repository.

Otherwise, if your need is to be sure that you never modify the original repo, it must be managed by your access rights on this original repo.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this before, where a "read only" copy was a deployment copy versus a development copy.  In addition to using --depth 1, we used a deployment key --but if you can't do that then you should be able to create a user for this that doesn't have write access to the repo, and prevent write access to that user's directories  by other users with unix permissions.  For a small team that needs a quick solution, this can work.